# Non negative distributional derivative imply a.e. monotonicity

Tags: real-analysis, weak-derivatives

Suppose $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ and that $f'\le 0$ in the sense of distribution, i.e. $\forall \varphi \in C^\infty_C(\mathbb{R})$ $\varphi\ge0$ we have $\int_\mathbb{R}f\varphi'\ge 0$.

How can I prove that $f$ is almost everywhere decreasing ($f(x+y)\le f(x)$ for almost every $x\in \mathbb{R}, y \in \mathbb{R}^+$)?

My obvious attempt was to use the fact that $ \lim_{h\to 0} \int \varphi(x) \frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}dx\le 0$ to get a local statement:  for sufficiently small $h$ we have that $f(x)-f(x-h)\le 0$ for a.e. $x,h>0$, where $h$ is small. Can I proceed from this?

Comment: your question is a bit confusing,
sometimes you talk about $f$, then there is $u$ in your attempt.
also, you want $f(x+y)\geq f(x)$ for a.e. $x\in\mathbb R,\, y>0$, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I fixed it!

Comment: There are still needless typos in your question.  $f' \leq 0$, but $f$ is increasing?  $f(x + y) \geq f(x)$ for *all* $y \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Are you familiar with mollification?  That is often the cheap way to demonstrate these types of results.

Comment: Oh very nice! Thank you very much! It is basically 1 line proof